# file_exists returns false when the files does exist in OPENCART

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am uploading a file in the OPENCART admin panel (I have designed a backend page where it takes a file for upload and a second button used for downloading).

The file is uploading correctly to the **/var/www/html/projectFolder/system/upload/** directory. I want to check that the file exists in this directory and only then show the download button. But when I am using this script:

```
if(file_exists($file_path)){echo "show Download Button"}
```

It is always returning me FALSE, but the file **is present** there.

NOTE: $file_path = http://www.domain.com/system/upload pasted in direct address bar showing file in browser BUT RETURNING FALSE in code.

How can I fix this?

Comment: File path should be a absolute path like /var/www/ ..

Comment: Sometimes, this problem occure due to file permission. So please check the file permission. File permission should be `664`